# N-FET not working (leaking at drain-source while gate is at GND)

Tags: mosfet

Trying to use N-FET [2N7002](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/2N7002P.pdf) but I am unable to make it work.

I would like to control N-FET (control LED) so when I put 3.3V at gate it turns on and when I put 0 (GND) at gate that it turns off.

What I am getting is that my LED is dimming (light glow) when my gate voltage is 0V (GND).

Also measuring at drain-source I get voltage drop of 1.8V.

I tried to replace 330Ω with 100Ω, also tried to remove 100Ω at the gate, all of that didn't work.

Just to add that when connecting 3.3V to gate LED turns on (works).

Circuit is as in diagram below:

[image]

Comment: Is your gate drive signal pulling low or leaving the gate floating? Putting 0 and leaving the gate floating are two different actions. Try putting a 1k resistor from gate to source - if the problem goes away, you are not actually zeroing the gate and stray charge can cause Cgs to self-charge a little bit and the device to weakly turn on.

Comment: IDSS is about a microamp for these devices - is that enough to produce any light in your LED. Measure the current.

Comment: Althoug in this case it will work, note that the 2N7002 would better be driven with a \$V_{GS}\$ of 5 V (check Fig 8 in the datasheet). You'd better use **logic level mosfets** when you want to use 3.3V as gate voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka IDSS is spec'd at 60V. Wouldn't it be about 20 times less at 3.3V?

Comment: Sorry for missing it out, I have put Pulldown (10K) also tried with 1K.

Comment: How can Drain-Source be 1.8V while Gate is attached to GND (Hard 0)?

Comment: @Huisman IDSS is not linear with VDS - it could remain largely constant from 60 volts down to a couple of volts (unless of course you have some link that says otherwise). Concrete data on these things are hard to find on the internet (I've discovered).

Comment: Double and triple check the pin-out of your device. You may have drain & source reversed.

Comment: @brhans yea.. I did it at least 5 times and also have others :) never enough.. good point... but didn't help.

Comment: In general what voltage drop should be measured at D-S if Gate is 0V? I still cannot understand that 1.8V? How is that possible if Gate is 0V D-S should be closed right?

Comment: 'closed' is ambiguous. Do you mean 'closed' like a switch, or 'closed' like a gate? Rather use terms like 'on' or 'off'. In any event, if you're expecting your N-FET to behave like a switch then you should expect to measure Vds or either 0V (when it's switched on) or 3.3V (when it's switched off). A Vds of 1.8V implies that it's either half-on/half-off, or connected backwards and the body diode is conducting (or the N-FET is dead and anything could happen).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. After more testing for sure orientation is good, also I have removed LED and then 3.3 is measured, no voltage drop. If I add the LED again the same situation. How can LED affect operation of mosfet?